# Assembly Code - GCC optimized function vs not

Tags: assembly

I want to learn more about how GCC optimizes C programs.  I have did a disas of a random function both optimized and unoptimized and I want to look at some of the differences.  Off the top of my head, the optimized assembly has less jumps, and seems to use registers mostly, while the unoptimized is using memory more often.  What other differences are there to note about these two?

UNOPTIMIZED

```
Dump of assembler code for function countPairsUpTo:
0x080485b1 <countPairsUpTo+0>:  push   %ebp
0x080485b2 <countPairsUpTo+1>:  mov    %esp,%ebp
0x080485b4 <countPairsUpTo+3>:  sub    $0x10,%esp
0x080485b7 <countPairsUpTo+6>:  call   0x8048418 <mcount@plt>
0x080485bc <countPairsUpTo+11>: movl   $0x0,-0x4(%ebp)
0x080485c3 <countPairsUpTo+18>: movl   $0x0,-0x8(%ebp)
0x080485ca <countPairsUpTo+25>: jmp    0x80485fa <countPairsUpTo+73>
0x080485cc <countPairsUpTo+27>: mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x080485cf <countPairsUpTo+30>: shl    $0x2,%eax
0x080485d2 <countPairsUpTo+33>: add    0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x080485d5 <countPairsUpTo+36>: mov    (%eax),%eax
0x080485d7 <countPairsUpTo+38>: cmp    0x10(%ebp),%eax
0x080485da <countPairsUpTo+41>: jne    0x80485f6 <countPairsUpTo+69>
0x080485dc <countPairsUpTo+43>: mov    0xc(%ebp),%edx
0x080485df <countPairsUpTo+46>: add    $0x8,%edx
0x080485e2 <countPairsUpTo+49>: mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x080485e5 <countPairsUpTo+52>: shl    $0x2,%eax
0x080485e8 <countPairsUpTo+55>: lea    (%edx,%eax,1),%eax
0x080485eb <countPairsUpTo+58>: mov    (%eax),%eax
0x080485ed <countPairsUpTo+60>: cmp    0x14(%ebp),%eax
0x080485f0 <countPairsUpTo+63>: jne    0x80485f6 <countPairsUpTo+69>
0x080485f2 <countPairsUpTo+65>: addl   $0x1,-0x4(%ebp)
0x080485f6 <countPairsUpTo+69>: addl   $0x1,-0x8(%ebp)
0x080485fa <countPairsUpTo+73>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x080485fd <countPairsUpTo+76>: cmp    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048600 <countPairsUpTo+79>: ja     0x80485cc <countPairsUpTo+27>
0x08048602 <countPairsUpTo+81>: mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
0x08048605 <countPairsUpTo+84>: leave  
0x08048606 <countPairsUpTo+85>: ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

OPTIMIZED

```
Dump of assembler code for function countPairsUpTo:
0x08048570 <countPairsUpTo+0>:  push   %ebp
0x08048571 <countPairsUpTo+1>:  mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048573 <countPairsUpTo+3>:  push   %edi
0x08048574 <countPairsUpTo+4>:  push   %esi
0x08048575 <countPairsUpTo+5>:  push   %ebx
0x08048576 <countPairsUpTo+6>:  call   0x8048418 <mcount@plt>
0x0804857b <countPairsUpTo+11>: mov    0xc(%ebp),%ebx
0x0804857e <countPairsUpTo+14>: mov    0x10(%ebp),%esi
0x08048581 <countPairsUpTo+17>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%ecx
0x08048584 <countPairsUpTo+20>: mov    $0x0,%edi
0x08048589 <countPairsUpTo+25>: test   %ecx,%ecx
0x0804858b <countPairsUpTo+27>: je     0x80485b2 <countPairsUpTo+66>
0x0804858d <countPairsUpTo+29>: mov    $0x0,%edi
0x08048592 <countPairsUpTo+34>: mov    $0x0,%edx
0x08048597 <countPairsUpTo+39>: cmp    %esi,(%ebx,%edx,4)
0x0804859a <countPairsUpTo+42>: jne    0x80485ab <countPairsUpTo+59>
0x0804859c <countPairsUpTo+44>: mov    0x14(%ebp),%eax
0x0804859f <countPairsUpTo+47>: cmp    %eax,0x8(%ebx,%edx,4)
0x080485a3 <countPairsUpTo+51>: sete   %al
0x080485a6 <countPairsUpTo+54>: movzbl %al,%eax
0x080485a9 <countPairsUpTo+57>: add    %eax,%edi
0x080485ab <countPairsUpTo+59>: add    $0x1,%edx
0x080485ae <countPairsUpTo+62>: cmp    %ecx,%edx
0x080485b0 <countPairsUpTo+64>: jne    0x8048597 <countPairsUpTo+39>
0x080485b2 <countPairsUpTo+66>: mov    %edi,%eax
0x080485b4 <countPairsUpTo+68>: pop    %ebx
0x080485b5 <countPairsUpTo+69>: pop    %esi
0x080485b6 <countPairsUpTo+70>: pop    %edi
0x080485b7 <countPairsUpTo+71>: pop    %ebp
0x080485b8 <countPairsUpTo+72>: ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

C code:

```
uint    countPairsUpTo      (int        index,
                 int*       intArray,
                 int        first,
                 int        second
                )
{
  uint  i;
  uint  sum = 0;

  for  (i = 0;  i < index;  i++)
    if  ( (first == intArray[i])  &&  (second == intArray[i+2]) )
      sum++;

  return(sum);
}
```

Comment: You question may be closed because SO is for more specific questions about programming. Hardly someone will read it and tell you every difference. You need to do it yourself.

Comment: It would help if you posted the original C code, too, so people can understand what the code is doing.

Comment: I'm not looking for every difference.  Just a few.

Comment: Have you actually tried to compile that C code? I've never seen `return(sum)` in C. Either way, where does the `call mcount@plt` in the assembly come from? There is no corresponding function call in the C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one major difference you can spot at a first glance is amount of memory accesses.

Consider unoptimized case:

```
mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
shl    $0x2,%eax
add    0xc(%ebp),%eax 
mov    (%eax),%eax
add    0xc(%ebp),%eax
mov    (%eax),%eax
cmp    0x10(%ebp),%eax
```

Every time any of the variables is modified it is written back to its allocated memory location. This even applies to intermediate addresses, which are explicitly computed, stored into memory (respective pointer variable, `intArray` in this case) and only then dereferenced with a separate instruction.

In optimized case, values stay in registers and iteration is done with addressing arithmetic (so, no intermediate pointer variable calculation):

```
cmp    %esi,(%ebx,%edx,4)
```

single instruction whose effect is to compare `esi` to value at location `ebx` + `edx` * 4.

No need to make 3 loads, 3 stores and shift left by 2 (multiply by 4).